# Concurrent Modification Exception in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, concurrentmodification, listiterator

I am getting the ConcurrentModificationException while executing this code. I am unable to figure out why it is happening?

```
private void verifyBookingIfAvailable(ArrayList<Integer> list, int id) {

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                int value = iterator.next();
                if (value == id) {
                    int index = list.indexOf(id);

                    if (index != -1) {
                        list.remove(index);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code seems strictly equivalent to `while (list.remove(Integer.valueOf(id)));` unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @assylias. Well, you are not missing anything. You're absolutely correct. No need to iterate here at all. Nice catch :)

Comment: @RohitJain Just need to make sure that `remove(Object)` is called and not `remove(int)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are removing the element in the list using the `list` reference itself, which can throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. Note that, this might work sometimes, but not always, and is not guaranteed to work perfectly.

Also, even though you use `Iterator` to iterate your list, you still shouldn't use `list.remove`, you should only use `iterator.remove()` to remove the elements, else it won't make any difference, whether you use iterators or enhanced for-loop.

So, use `iterator.remove()` to remove elements.

```
if (index != -1) {
    iterator.remove(value);
}
```

See this post: - [java-efficient-equivalent-to-removing-while-iterating-a-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: tbh, your answer is detailed enough :)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR.. Haha :) Possibly, but that post is highly detailed to be compared with my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you answer is really comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because you're trying to remove elements from the `ArrayList` while iterating over them. To overcome this issue, use the [java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Unless the list is used in a multi-threaded environment, CopyOnWriteArrayList is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the ArrayList iterator isn't designed to enable modification while you're iterating on it.

So, to avoid more serious bugs coming from incoherent data, it has a modification count which is updated when you remove an item and checked when you iterate :

From ArrayList.java :

```
411     public E remove(int index) {
412         rangeCheck(index);
413 
414         modCount++;
415         E oldValue = elementData(index);
416 
417         int numMoved = size - index - 1;
418         if (numMoved > 0)
419             System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
420                              numMoved);
421         elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work
422 
423         return oldValue;
424     }
     ...
779 
780         final void checkForComodification() {
781             if (modCount != expectedModCount)
782                 throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
783         }
```

As specified in the javadoc :

> The returned list iterator is fail-fast.

To avoid this problem, use the iterator to remove the current element, not the list directly. The `remove` method of the iterator ensures the iterator is kept coherent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void verifyBookingIfAvailable(ArrayList<Integer> list, int id) {

        List<Integer> tempList =new ArrayList<Integer>();
    tempList.addAll(list);

     for(Integer value :tempList) {

         if (value == 1) {
             int index = tempList.indexOf(1);

             if (index != -1) {

                 list.remove(index);
             }
         }
 }
}
```

while iteration you are removing objects

Comment: wouldnt it still throw exception ??

Comment: This is what you shouldn't do to modify the list to start with. Then comes iterator, which should be used. But even in iterators, you can't use `list.remove`. You have to use `iterator.remove`. So your answer doesn't help. Because, you just moved a step backward rather than moving forward.

Comment: I did few changes it works. though it may not be good approach

Comment: @Sura. Yeah you are right. It works, but its not a good idea to make a copy of your list. You should straight forward use an Iterator. That's what they are there for.